# Is there an equivalent to "partial class" for aspx pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, include

I have a very very very long page and for making the html easier to read, i'd like to split the pages in several sub-pages.

To manage my controls on the page, I already split my code-behind page in several files.

I'd like to do the same with my aspx. How would I call those sub-page and how would I start them? (like, no *<%@ Page [...]...>*).

So far, I tried `<!-- #Include virtual="~/path/page.aspx" -->` with an empty aspx page (only 'test' in the aspx. no code behind).

It works, but then, VS2010 throw me a bunch of errors (*Too many characters in character literal.* )

### edit

I'd rather avoid using user controls :

I already use plenty of those. In this case, there's no need for reusability. Those controls would also mainly only contains other user controls. And I don't want to diverge too much from the layout of all my other pages (which are shorter). Most page have 3-4 controls on them but this one has like 50. I'd just like to split it in multiple html page.

Comment: While technically different, it sounds like "User Controls" would be appropriate for you.

Comment: To address your edit; the fact that you don't plan to re-use it doesn't mean it doesn't make sense as a user control.  It's not a bad idea at all to create a user control you use only once, simply as a way of pulling out the separate sections of the page into smaller logical components.  The reason to to would be if the coupling is so tight between that module and other aspects of the page that there is no effective means of separating them.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Improve load time? Is your page mainly to display info or collect user inputs?

Comment: Simply splitting the code in different files. And it's mainly to collect user inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was close to the answer. It seems the error thrown by VS2010 on the *html* went away after building the project. Still, I went back to having code-behind files for my sub-page, although VS sorta get confused about all the files.

Here's how I ended up splitting my page :

Parent aspx file :

```
<!-- #Include virtual="~/Page/subPage.aspx" -->
```

parent aspx.cs file :

```
public partial class myPage
```

Subpage aspx file :

> Plain html (no @Page, @Imports, etc.), user controls...

```
<div style="margin:20px 0px;">
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="table" />
</div>

<CUSTOMCTRL runat="server" />
```

Subpage aspx.cs file :

> public partial class myPage

Subpage aspx.designers.cs file :

> public partial class myPage

The only issue with this is the subpage designers : You need to manage them by hand.